# Nifi Expression Language how to assign a value to a variable

Tags: expression, apache-nifi

I'm using Nifi's Expression Language to compute 2 dates in order to stick them into a template. I like compute these dates ONCE and to use them into the template as much as I need. 
My Idea is to do something like:

```
dateStart = ${now():toNumber():minus(86400):format("YYYY-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:'00'")}
```

then use `${dateStart}` as I like

How can I assign the expression result to a var ?

Comment: Is your question: how to add a value to a FlowFile once and use it multiple times as it makes it way through the flow (what @Bryan-Bende answered below)? or how do you create a "global" variable once and re-use it multiple times throughout the flow ie. create a variable for when NiFi started processing?

Comment: the first. Bryan got the point. Tomorrow I'll try it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UpdateAttribute processor is used to add attributes to flow files. From the configuration screen of UpdateAttribute you can click the + icon in the top right to add a property and name it "dateStart" and set the value to your expression. After that you can reference ${dateStart} in other processor properties that support expression language.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a generateFlowFile with this property:

[image]